# Can a geodesic dome with a large flat open space on top be used as a kosher sukkah?

Tags: sukkah, sukkot, masechet-sukkah

I have a friend who proposed the idea of building a geodesic dome sukkah this year - but with a flat open space atop the dome so that the schach can lay flat atop the sukkah. we are intending this structure to be about 30 feet by 30 feet. and about 28 feet tall.

Is it kosher to build a sukkah inside of a semi-dome shaped structure with a flat roof?

Would laying the schach flat atop the smaller end of this dome the only way for this to be permissable?

Would it even perhaps be permissible  lay the schach on the slanted sections of the roof (like the image below)? we were potentially considering running hemp ropes in a criss cross pattern and weaving the schach between these ropes.

I've included photos of a model that my friend made with popsicle sticks of the shape we roughly intend to build. each popsicle stick represents a 7-foot-long bamboo pole.

[image: Sukkah structure]
[image: Friend's proposal of schach layout]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How much space will be between the vertical walls and the schach? Using ropes is problematic, but some kinds of twine can be ok. Unfortunately, you have to actually show the twine to a rabbi for him to pasken. It's definitely not recommended.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the last mishnah in the first perek of Sukkah, it talks about a wigwam sukkah. That seems like the same kind of question. https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.19b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en